# Adding custom body to botium testing conversations

Tags: javascript, bots

I'm trying to add location in the body of my request to several botium tests. 
The only way I've managed to do it is via custom asserters. Is it the reliable way to do this? Is it the only way to do this?

convo.txt

```
Market Snapshot near me
#begin
LOCATION

#me
Show me snapshot near me

#bot
There are 9 market snaps near your location.
CARDS snapshot

#end
LOCATION
```

LocationAsserter.js

```
module.exports = class LocationAsserter {
  constructor(context, caps = {}) {
    this.context = context;
    this.caps = caps;
  }

  assertConvoBegin({ convo, container, args }) {
    console.log(`MyAsserter assertConvoBegin: ${convo.header.name}`);
    this.caps.SIMPLEREST_BODY_TEMPLATE.location = {
      latitude: 30.4,
      longitude: -97.7,
    };

    return Promise.resolve();
  }

  assertConvoStep({ convo, convoStep, args, botMsg }) {
    console.log(`MyAsserter assertConvoStep, botMessage: ...`);
    return Promise.resolve();
  }

  assertConvoEnd({ convo, container, msgs, args }) {
    console.log(`MyAsserter assertConvoEnd ${convo.header.name}, converstation: ...`);
    delete this.caps.SIMPLEREST_BODY_TEMPLATE.location;
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option, you can use the **[SIMPLEREST_REQUEST_HOOK capability](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/24510469/Generic+HTTP+S+JSON+Connector#SIMPLEREST_REQUEST_HOOK)** to change the HTTP request body with your own logic.

```
...
"SIMPLEREST_REQUEST_HOOK": "requestOptions.body.location = { latitude: 30.4, longitude: -97.7 }",
...
```

This hook is called just before any HTTP request is done.

*You can reference your own custom module or a Javascript file instead of inline code*

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I wanted to add this location only in certain conversations. Good to know anyway!